# Arduino: If Serial input string matches then continue otherwise keep asking for user input

Tags: arduino

I want to be able to have the user input a string and have it compared to another string and if it matches then the program can continue otherwise it continues to ask for an input.
I made a basic input that matches a string.

I'm not how sure how to approach the task of asking for continuous input.

```c
String defaultPassword = "pass1234";

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Enter password: ");
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

  while (Serial.available() > 0) {
    String inputPassword = Serial.readStringUntil('\n');
    inputPassword.trim();

    if (inputPassword == defaultPassword) 
    {
      Serial.print("Correct Input: ");
      Serial.println(inputPassword);
      Serial.println("Initializing...");
    } 
    else if (inputPassword != defaultPassword) 
    {
      Serial.print("Incorrect Input: ");
      Serial.println(inputPassword);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm not how sure how to approach the task of asking for continuous input.

- `void loop()` method will keep repeating once you enter it so you
  will be continuous checking for input throught `while (Serial.available() > 0)`
- create a `bool` variable and use it as a flag, change it's value to `ture` or `false` based your password string compare and you can check on that flag later to decide whether to ask the user for another input or continue.

```cxx
        bool flag = false;
        if (inputPassword == defaultPassword)
        {
          flag = true;
          Serial.print("Correct Input: ");
          Serial.println(inputPassword);
          Serial.println("Initializing...");
        } 
        else 
        {
          flag = false;
          Serial.print("Incorrect Input: ");
          Serial.println(inputPassword);
          Serial.print("Please enter password again.");
        }
        if(flag)
        {
         //rest of your logic here if user entered the desired input
        }
```

Comment: This worked perfectly using the boolean variables to flag for a valid input, thank you so much Mahmoud!